# How to use html and react in Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

My `<Header />` component obtains class `collapsed` in mobile view. I want to write test that will test mobile view scenario

```
it('should render mobile view', () => {

    const wrapper = mount(
        <div style={{width: '700px'}}>
            <Header content={headerData} useDOMNodeWidth={true} />
        </div>
    );

    expect(wrapper.find('.header-component').first().hasClass('collapsed')).to.equal(true);
});
```

After running test I have an AssertionError, so it seems that there is a problem with rendering. I assume that `render` method only accepts clean react component.

Any idea how I can test it ?

Answer (score 0):

Header component might be rendering mobile view based on some condition. You will have to inject that condition in Header component while/before rendering it.

For eg: I have components on web portals which shows different logos based on customer type. This customer type will be set in my appConfig before I render the component.

Comment: I dont think its a good approach. Test should be tuned for component, not component for test

Comment: I am not tuning component, I am setting up its environment. Logos get displayed depending on customer configuration from server. Since this is unit test, I will have to tell for which customer configuration, I am testing it.

Comment: but my case is totally different, the only one condition for mobile view in my component is width or window or parent component

Comment: Did you try with other enzyme API like : expect(wrapper.find('.header-component collapsed'),exists()).toBeTruthy()